# Kudu modules are not recognized in pyspark. Getting Module not found error even after setting the classpath using --jars

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am unable to use Kudu modules inside the pyspark code while the scala spark accepts it.

**Scala Spark Code:**

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# spark-shell --jars /root/jars/org.apache.kudu_kudu-spark_2.10-1.5.0.jar
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = yarn, app id = application_1608199358512_0011).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_191)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
import org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu._
```

**Pyspark Code: Getting Module not found error**

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# pyspark --jars /root/jars/org.apache.kudu_kudu-spark_2.10-1.5.0.jar
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:16:51)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1.3.0.1.0-187
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.5 (default, Apr  2 2020 13:16:51)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu
>>>
```

Can someone help me why it is working in scala spark and not in pyspark?

Comment: did you `pip install kudu-python`? https://pypi.org/project/kudu-python/

Comment: Also check this out https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-do-you-connect-to-Kudu-via-PySpark/td-p/66765

Answer (score 0):

The kudu imports in scala are working because you are importing a jar but when you try to import the same jar into python environment it's natural that it will throw error . Kudu support in pyspark is limited as of now see -https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/KUDU-1603 ,

But if you really want to create the kudu context in pyspark you can use this

```
kc = sc._jvm.org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu.KuduContext("kudu.master:7051")
```

Comment: I downloaded spark version3 binaries in my local windows system and I initiated pyspark shell without any parameters.
I submitted the following command and the import was successful. 
>>> spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("kudu-spark.jar file path")
>>> from org.apache.kudu.spark.kudu import *

This import was successful on windows system with spark v3 binaries. But the same thing when executed on HDP sandbox or Cloudera Real cluster, it seems to fail.  

I have not tried to create KuduContext with the sc._jvm yet. I will try and leave a comment.

Comment: I have initiated pyspark shell with --packages parameter in local system windows. 
pyspark --packages org.apache.kudu:kudu-spark_2.10:1.5.0
Now without executing spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("sparkkudu.jar"), the import worked. 

Technically, both --jars and --packages does the same work. isn't it. Its just that the --jars option looks at a specific path and --packages looks in some online repository like maven. In such case why is the import failing when using pyspark --jars and why the import is successful when using pyspark --packages.

Comment: When you use packages option it downloads all the dependencies automatically needed for running a particular jar , while using the Jar option only adds the mentioned jars to your spark session

Comment: Also Shankar , you were using spark version 2.* In the original question , and now you are trying the spark 3 .

Comment: yes. I was using spark 2 in the original question. In my local i am using spark 3. In spark 2 nothing works. In local, it works with --packages but not --jars option.

Comment: Did you try the solution I suggested , I was able to get it up and running

Comment: No Aditya. I wasn't able to create kudu context. But the pyspark code worked without importing the package. In scala the import is required. But in pyspark the import statement fails.The pyspark code written to read a kudu table runs fine if the import statement is removed. So I thing in scala the import is mandatory but not in pyspark.